# Custom attachments styling in post view

Tags: customization, attachments

I am looking for easy styling list of .doc attachments in post. For example i want to put every in `<li></li>` tags and do some proper styling.

So far I am get my post content this way:

```
 <?php
              query_posts('cat=13');
              while (have_posts()) : the_post();
              the_content();
              endwhile;
            ?>
```

Comment: Please provide information about what you've already tried.

Comment: in a code provided I am pulling posts content with atachments, but I am unable to do some styling with it> i want to have <li> tags around every atatachment

Answer (score 1):

### Retrieve the attachments

There's a pretty unknown, but handy function in core: `get_children();`, which accepts an array of arguments. One of those is `post_mime_type`.

```
$attachments = get_children( array(
    'post_parent'    => get_the_ID(),
    'post_type'      => 'attachment', 
    'numberposts'    => -1,
    'post_status'    => 'publish',
    'post_mime_type' => 'application/msword'
) );
```

If you're unsure about the MIME types of your doc files, you can simply call

```
var_dump( get_post_mime_type( get_the_ID() ) );
```

on your `single.php` (or whatever theme template displays your single attachments to see the exact MIME type.

Here's a non complete list of possible MIME types for MS Word files:

```
.ext  | MIME Type
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
.doc  | application/msword
.dot  | application/msword
.docx | application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.wordprocessingml.document
.dotx | application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.wordprocessingml.template
.docm | application/vnd.ms-word.document.macroEnabled.12
.dotm | application/vnd.ms-word.template.macroEnabled.12
```

### MarkUp

We then can puzzle together a list for them:

```
printf(
    '<ul><li></li></ul>',
    join( '</li><li>', wp_list_pluck( 'post_title', $attachments ) )
);
```